# UPDATE in mysql didn't work in my PHP page.

Tags: php, mysql, database

First of all I'm a rookie to Programming, I created a PHP page to update a value from my mysql(myadmin) database, but the value is not updating. I also tried to retrieve values from database it's working just fine but this UPDATE code is not working! I don't know why, please check out my code below.

```
$qs=mysql_query("update staff set review=$newrate where name=$rateuser");
$resu=mysql_query($qs);
```

All variables are double defined, assigned with proper values, checked and I tested variables using echo, table name is also checked, it's all fine, but I think the problem is with Update query, I searched internet for the syntax but it's not different than mine. Please help me out

Comment: missing quotes, and basic error checking

Comment: 2 things, first, you are executing the query twice.  Second, you need single quotes around the variables is they are not integers.

Comment: Try putting your variables: $newrate, $rateuser in single quotes.

Comment: $qs=mysql_query("update staff set review='$newrate' where name='$rateuser'"); like that.

Answer (score 1):

How are $newrate and $rateuser set?

```
mysql_query("UPDATE staff SET review = '".mysql_real_escape_string($newrate)."' WHERE name = '".mysql_real_escape_string($rateuser) ."'");
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$qs=mysql_query("update staff set review='$newrate' where name='$rateuser'");
```

Do not use second line.

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need some `"` around your values `$newrate` and `$rateuser`

But if you did an echo, why not actually echo for us what the query-string becomes?

Answer (score 0):

You need single quotes around string values on your query:

```
$qs=mysql_query("update staff set review='$newrate' where name='$rateuser'");
```

(assuming both variables are strings)